# yii CUniqueValidator specify compare attribute

Tags: php, validation, yii

I have a signup form that allows users to input either their email or phone number in a form field `email_or_phone`. I wrote a validation function which i used in the `rules()` function to ensure that the value submitted is either a valid email or phone number. The value is then assigned to the correct model attribute in the `afterValidation()` function.

My problem is, the model attributes `email` and `phone` are supposed to be unique. I wrote the `afterValidation()` function to test for uniqueness against the appropriate table column. But the code doesnt work. Below is my `afterValidation()` function:

```
protected function afterValidate(){
    parent::afterValidate();

    if(!$this->hasErrors() && $this->isNewRecord){

        $validator = new CEmailValidator;

        if($validator->validateValue($this->email_or_phone)){
            $validator = new CUniqueValidator;
            $validator->attributeName = 'email';
            $validator->validate($model, 'email_or_phone');
            if(!$this->hasErrors()) $this->email = $this->email_or_phone;
        }else{
            $validator = new CUniqueValidator;
            $validator->attributeName = 'phone';
            $validator->validate($model, 'email_or_phone');
            if(!$this->hasErrors()) $this->phone = $this->email_or_phone;
        }
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You can rather use Yii inbuilt unique validator. 
Ref: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUniqueValidator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `CUniqueValidator` for each `email` and `phone`, but configure `'allowEmpty' = true`.

Also define setter for email and phone field where you check if it is phone or email and set it or leave it empty.

To get uniqueness error message on `email_or_phone` add to it messages from both `email` and `phone`. But to get it to work, a little trick is needed. You have to define your own validation rule as a separate class extending from `CValidator`, so you could call protected method from `CUniqueValidator`:

```
class MyValidator extends CValidator
{
protected function validateAttribute($object, $attribute)
{
    // Some validation:
    if(!isPhoneOrEmail($object->$attribute))
    {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'This is not phone or email');
    }
    // Now check phone and email
    $validator = new CuniqueValidator();
    $validator->allowEmpty = true;
    $validator->validateAttribute($object, 'phone');
    // Now get errors for phone attribute
    $errors = $object->getErrors('phone');
    if($errors)
    {
        foreach($errors as $error)
        {
            $this->addError($attribute, $error);
        }
    }

    // Same for email
}
}
```

Comment: I considered this approach. But with this approach the error doesnt appear in the `email_or_phone` form field. It would ether show up in the `email` form field or the `phone` form field and the sign-up form contains neither of these.

Comment: You could *additionally* validate uniqueness in you custom validation method and pass error message to it.

Comment: How do i do that using yii `CUniqueValidator`?

Comment: Updated my answer with explanation of how to add messages from `phone` to `email_or_phone`